# Mvc3 DropdownlistFor error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc3 dropdownlist containing Organization list.I am able to fill that using the code below.But when I submit the form, I am getting Id instead of name and the corresponding Id is null.

Controller

```
    ViewBag.DropDownList =organizationModelList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() });
return view();
```

Model

```
public class SubscriberModel
    {
        public OrgnizationList Organization { get; set; }
        public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
        public SubscriberDetails SubscriberDetails { get; set; }
    }
    public class OrgnizationList
    {
        [Required]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

View
@

```
model FleetTracker.WebUI.Models.SubscriberModel
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Account")) {
<div>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Organization.Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownList, "---Select a value---")
</div>
}
```

[image]

When I change it tom => m.Organization.Id, then the modelstate will change to not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#DropDownList").change(function () {
                    $("#Organization_Id").val($(this).val());
                    $("#Organization_Name").val($("#DropDownList option:selected").text());

                });
            }); 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Organization.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Organization.Name)
    @Html.DropDownList("DropDownList", string.Empty)
```

controller

```
ViewBag.DropDownList = new SelectList(organizationModelList, "Id", "Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the name to be returned instead of the Id? If yes then instead of this:

> ViewBag.DropDownList =organizationModelList.Select(x => new
>   SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() });

do this:

```
ViewBag.DropDownList =organizationModelList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Name });
```

Then remove the `Required` attribute for `OrgnizationList.Id`. If `OrgnizationList` is an entity, which I think it is, then you'll run yourself into trouble. I suggest you have a viewmodel that represents your input. So you don't have to deal with **unnecessary required fields**.

But what if the `Name` is not unique? Why can't you just accept the `Id` and save it in your data store? You are not modifying the name of `OrgnizationList`, I assume.

**UPDATE:** 
If you really need both then tuck the Id on a hidden field:

**Your controller method**

```
ViewBag.DropDownList =organizationModelList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id });
```

**Your model**

```
public class SubscriberModel
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    // your other properties goeshere
}
```

**Your view**

```
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.OrganizationId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Organization.Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownList, "---Select a value---")
</div>
```

and a bit of js needed...

```
$("Organization_Name").change(function(){
    $("#OrganizationId").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @Von.I am getting only the name.But I want both Id and Name.